# Typescript logic to store the common times being used across the days of the week

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have a typescript/angular application where a user can enter specific times during a day. Please see the image below to get a better understanding. I am having trouble figuring out the logic to be able to loop through all the times for every day and record any overlapping times. The times are stored in json format.

There is a lot of code but basically the code to push the times to the json is:

```js
private pushTime(dayName : string, time : string[]) : number {
    return      this.dealEditDaypartingCtrl.deal.deal_settings.dayparting.schedule[dayName].push(time);
 }
```

In the code above 'time' is an array e.g. ["03:45", "13:00"]

The array is stored in json format like this:

```
schedule:{  
      "Monday":[ ["04:00", "12:00"]],
      "Tuesday":[ ["05:00", "15:15"]],
      "Wednesday":[ ["04:00", "13:00"]],
      "Thursday":[ ["07:00", "13:00"]],
      "Friday":[ ["03:45", "13:00"]],
      "Saturday":[ ["05:30", "16:30"]],
      "Sunday":[ ["07:00", "14:00]],
      "Week":[[]]
  }
```

So for this example for week, it should be "Week":[["08:00", "12:00]], as 8-12 is the only common time shared across all days

[Example times across days of the week](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ju86h.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through all of them and compare to see if there're overlaps.

You can loop through your schedule like:

```
lookForOverlapsInSchedule(schedule: any): any[] {
  let days: string[] = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(schedule); // get object propery names in array like ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', ...]
  days.forEach(
    (dayOne) => {
      let overlapsCounter: number = 0;
      days.forEach(
        (dayTwo) => {
          if (compareDayTimes(schedule[dayOne], schedule[dayTwo]) {
            overlapsCounter++;
          }
        }
      );
      if (overlapsCounter == 7) {
        // you found an overlap
      }
    }
  )
}

compareDayTimes(dayOne: any, dayTwo: any): boolean {
  // compare dayOne and dayTwo for overlaps 
  // return true if they overlap, false if they don't
}
```

This is just a pointer in the right direction, the code won't work on it's own but might give you an idea on how to implement your own solution.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me! I will give this a try. Would this just check for identical times that are present for each day? i.e. if 8-12 was the specific time entered for each day?

Comment: You need to implement your own algorithm for comparing date/times. I could only suggest to track overlaps in another array and in the end of each iteration, if all days overlap to take the unique overlap cycle. I'm not here to do your job for you, but rather to point you in the right direction.